# Choosing between DI (without container) and Composition

Tags: object-oriented, python, dependency-injection, composition

I'm working on a classes that are designed to read a defined file format; said format is comprised of 2 separate files (`FileA` and `FileB`). For ease of use, the format is referred to as the `FileA` format, but a valid "file" **must** have a `FileB`. The files share the same path prefix, but alter in suffix; therefore my current classes appears as:

```
class FileReaderA:
    def __init__(self, path: pathlib.Path):
            self.a = path.with_suffix('.fa')
            self.b = FileReaderB(path)
    # methods related to operating on FileA types

class FileReaderB:
    def __init__(self, path: pathlib.Path):
            self.b = path.with_suffix('.fa')
    # methods related to operating on FileB types
```

The classes are separated since `FileReaderB` does not depend on `FileReaderA` and can be used independently to read `FileB` types, however a valid `FileA` requires its associated `FileB`. Therefore, composition made sense, at first. Now I'm wondering if DI is the more appropriate solution, but it requires that `FileReaderB` be explicitly instantiated and passed to the constructor of `FileReaderA`, which is less than ideal form a user standpoint with this API:

```
>>> frb = FileReaderB(path)
>>> fra = FileReaderA(path, frb)
```

Thus I am forced to abstract it by using a factory:

```
def reader(path: pathlib.Path):
    return FileReaderA(path, FileReaderB(path))


>>> fra = reader(path)
```

This seems verbose and I feel as though I'm introducing more code and layers of abstraction to achieve the same result, all around the guise for better unit testing of decoupled classes.

What is wrong with just using Composition over enforcing DI?

Comment: Are you certain that `FileReaderA` depends upon `FileReaderB`?  On the surface it sounds like you have two separate file formats.  To accomplish some goal, an operation may need both `FileReaderA` and `FileReaderB` at the same time, but is this a responsibility of `FileReaderA`, or can it be pulled out into some other class?

Comment: @Matthew They are indeed 2 separate file formats, however, to convey information correctly, Record 1 of `FileReaderA` needs the information of Record 1 of `FileReaderB`. Independently their data is valid, but means nothing when disassociated.

Comment: It may make your system easier to write if you focus on providing separate abstractions for reading A files and reading B files.  Then you can write some logic that deals with them simultaneously.  At which point, if you move the calculation into a new class, it may no longer care that they're files at all.  The sole purpose is to break the problem down into smaller, testable chunks, this may also help with your dependency problem.

Comment: DI gives you flexibility to reuse the same component under different circumstances, but to me, it doesn't look like that's needed here. Making FileReaderB a constructor parameter of FileReaderA sort of implies that the B part could vary (in implementation, format), which is probably not the case. As for testing, DI lets you pass in a test double, e.g. to avoid accessing the file system in a test, but you don't get that here. You can either test the A and B readers separately (as they are), or extract the partial A-reading logic into its own class, and have FileReaderA be composed of those two.

Comment: @Matthew Possibly, but then I feel as though we've gone full circle; I pass a file path to `Processer` and it must instantiate each of the reader abstractions in its constructor; thus we've arrived at composition.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Is it typical to not use DI in a class that is built around accessing the file system? I know with say a `Config` class, you can mock a configuration and see how an interface behaves, but my classes simply read data from files and therefore cannot be mocked (they read and output what they've read). Additionally, what would be the benefit of creating a third class that is composed of the two independent readers vice how it currently is?

Comment: There are essentially two schools of thought when it comes to unit testing. One is where every single class is isolated with every dependency mocked; this is not necessarily always a good idea. The other is where units are more like related bundles of components that are instantiated and tested together ("mini integration tests"), except where that's inconvenient (network/db/filesystem access), with such components being mocked. So my remark (and the first point in Doc Brown's answer) was that from that perspective, this design doesn't give you that particular benefit. 1/2

Comment: And besides, you might not be after that benefit, and that's OK. The next thing to consider is DI for purely design reasons; in design terms, at the cost of some extra complexity, DI gives you flexibility to replace B - but again, if that's not a capability you need, then the extra complexity is probably not worth it. The final question is do you want to be able to test the A-specific logic separately from the combined (A+B) logic. If so, extracting the A-specific part would let you do that without compromising the design of FileReaderA - that's what my remark was about. 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Excellent, thank you for clarifying. I was quite content with my use of composition (makes sense in terms of object relationship), but stumbling across DI made me question its use. Sounds like the method of testing would be a real driver in determining whether or not to use it. Additionally, you made note of not replacing `B`, and that holds true; I could understand the need for DI if `B` was to ever be a different implementation. Therefore, it seems like a class that uses composition to house `A` and `B` (implemented separately) would be best.

Answer (score 2):

The questions I would ask here are:

- can one sensibly unit test a `FileReaderA` with an injected `MockFileReaderB` and achieve independence of I/O operations that way (to make such a test simpler and faster)?
- are `FileReaderA` and `FileReaderB` both so complex that making a real unit test for `FileReaderA`, isolated from `FileReaderB`, may be beneficial? So when the test fails, you know for sure `FileReaderA` is broken, not `FileReaderB`?

I guess the answer to the first question is "no", since a `FileReaderA` will probably require I/O operations anyway. The second question is something only you can answer.

Comment: Could you expand on why I/O operations would make testing problematic?

Comment: If you wanted to write unit tests, dealing with in-memory streams may be much simpler than dealing with discs.

Comment: @pasta_sauce: unit tests with I/O are not necessarily problematic, but with I/O, tests are often faster and simpler. The question is surely, how fast you will need them to be. Have a look at [Martin Fowler's site](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) and his remarks about the speed of unit tests.

Comment: @DocBrown To the second question, it is possible to write a test that if failed, it would indicated that `FileReaderA` is broken and not `FileReaderB`. Given that answer, how does that aid in determining if composition would be best over DI? Additionally, in your comment did you mean "...but without* I/O..."? I would think that tests would be slower when it comes to I/O.

Comment: @pasta_sauce: yes, I mant "without I/O". And as I said, you have to answer the second question to yourself, not to me. If you think DI is not necessary for making your unit tests for `FileReaderA` reliable, go ahead, trust your instinct.

Comment: @DocBrown Understood. My question was built around my findings on the use of DI, which lead me to wonder if DI should always be used (therefore classes should always be designed around it) or if it case-by-case (where composition may be better than DI).

Comment: @pasta_sauce: DI is not an end in itself, it is a means to an end. If you see no value in DI today, but tomorrow you miss it for unit testing, it should actually not be too hard to refactor this code, as long as you followed the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

```
self.b = FileReaderB(path)
```

is that you can never do:

```
class FileReaderB2 : FileReaderB
{
    //some overridden methods
}
```

and then use it in your FileReaderA

Which, some would say, is the whole point of classes.

Comment: And I see that here, DI is useful. However, since `FileReaderB` is parsing a know binary format, I cannot foresee a need for a class that extends it and overrides methods. Others have suggested a 3rd class (lets call it `Reader`) that is composed of the two individual format readers; this is the way I've gone so far. What would make this method less viable?

Comment: the obvs example is in unit tests

Comment: the second obvs example is if the format of the file is changed

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and considerations! I think after all this, composition is still fine.